# video streaming flask, open cv y Raspberry pi

Tags: flask, opencv, raspberry-pi

espero se encuentren muy bien

tengo una duda

estoy intentando realizar una captura de un video streaming que lo realizo con Raspberry pi4

el codigo es este:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)


def generate_frames():
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while True
                success,frame=cap.read()
                if not success:
                        break
                else:
                        ret,buffer=cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame)
                        frame=buffer.tobytes()

                yield(b'--frame\r\n'
                        b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route("/")
def index():
        return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/video')
def video():
        return Response(generate_frames(),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

me transmite el video normal, pero al realizar con esta función, no me transmite ningun video

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

camara = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def generador_frames():
    while True:
        ok, imagen = obtener_frame_camara()
        if not ok:
            break
        else:
            yield b"--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + imagen + b"\r\n"


def obtener_frame_camara():
    ok, frame = camara.read()
    if not ok:
        return False, None
    # Codificar la imagen como JPG
    _, bufer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
    imagen = bufer.tobytes()
    return True, imagen

@app.route("/")
def index():
        return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/streaming_camara')
def video():
        return Response(generador_frames(),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

cuando ejecuto el segudno programa desde mi pc, me funciona normal, sin embargo si lo ejecuto desde la raspberry pi no me muestra nada de video streaming...

Soy nuevo, alguien me puede explicar por favor...

necesito que la funcione en ambos casos...

probe ambos en la PC y la raspberry

Ambos funciona en la PC, pero solo el primero codigo funciona en raspberry pi